# Difficulty with covariant/contravariant vector sets

Tags: tensors

I'm reading ["An Introduction to Tensors for Students of Physics and Engineering"](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/Numbers/Math/documents/Tensors_TM2002211716.pdf) (Kolecki 2002) and am stuck on page 18 (page 22 in the PDF). The author claims that, in a 3-dimensional Euclidean space, with two bases $u, v, w$ and $x, y, z$, we can define a contravariant basis set as $$\mathbf{e^{(1)}} = \frac{\partial{\mathbf{r}}}{\partial{u}},\ \mathbf{e^{(2)}} = \frac{\partial{\mathbf{r}}}{\partial{v}},\ \mathbf{e^{(3)}} = \frac{\partial{\mathbf{r}}}{\partial{w}}$$
where $\mathbf{r} = x\mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j} + z\mathbf{k}$. Also, we can define a covariant basis set $$ \mathbf{e_{(1)}} = \mathbf{\nabla}u,\ \mathbf{e_{(2)}} = \mathbf{\nabla}v,\ \mathbf{e_{(3)}} = \mathbf{\nabla}w$$

Since these are covariant and contravariant vector sets, by definition we should have $\mathbf{e^{(1)}} \cdot \mathbf{e_{(1)}} = 1$, and the paper states that this is true. But I get a different result than the author when I try to do the proof: $$\begin{align} \mathbf{e^{(1)}} \cdot \mathbf{e_{(1)}} = \frac{\partial{\mathbf{r}}}{\partial{u}} \cdot \mathbf{\nabla}u & = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial{u}} \left( x\mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j} + z\mathbf{k}\right) \right) \cdot \left(\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} \mathbf{i} + \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}} \mathbf{j} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \mathbf{k} \right) u \right) \\ & = \left( \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{u}} \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} \right) + \left( \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}} \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}\right) + \left( \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{u}} \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{z}}\right) \\ &= 1 + 1 + 1 = 3\end{align}$$

In the paper, the author's first step in the proof is the same as the second line in mine, but he then gets $...=\partial{u}/\partial{u} = 1$ somehow. I don't believe the author is wrong, but I don't see how he gets that result. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Unlike ordinary derivatives, it’s not generally true that ${\partial x\over\partial u}{\partial u\over\partial x}=1$.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be a source of error and I see that that's true. The only way I can see to get to $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{u}}$ from line 2 is to "factor out" the partial derivatives of $u$ on the top and bottom of this expression, resulting in $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{u}}\left(\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{x}}+\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{y}}+\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{z}}\right)$ but then the part inside the parentheses has to be equal to 1, which it doesn't appear to be.

Comment: [This similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729357/expressing-contravariant-basis-vectors-in-terms-of-position-vector?rq=1) was answered in a way that makes sense to me; essentially you have $\frac{\partial{\mathbf{r}}}{\partial{u}} \cdot \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{\mathbf{r}}}$, but I'm not sure how to show this in any way more rigorous than "the $\partial{\mathbf{r}}$'s cancel."

Comment: Both the paper and the answer you cite explain the simplification, albeit rather tersely: apply the inverse function theorem and the chain rule (in reverse).